# Since Mr. Joval IS absent or WAS absent?

Tags: tense

I'm composing a minutes of the meeting, during that meeting Mr. Joval was absent, but I don't know which word should I use if is or was, could you please help me?

> Since Mr. Joval is absent

or

> Since Mr. Joval was absent

Answer (score 1):

As @James commented, this depends entirely on the tense in which the minutes are written. Ordinarily, minutes are written in the past tense ("The meeting was called to order at 1:15 PM", "A motion was made and seconded", "The motion passed 6 to 3", etc). In this case, use the past tense.

The exception would be if the minutes actually quoted someone talking about Mr. Joval's absence, but this would be most unusual - minutes ordinarily do not provide direct quotes, but rather provide a summary of the meeting's activities.